# UIScrollview scrollable when contentView's size increases left and top

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView- scv and a UIView - ocv that have been generated dynamically (no IB), I have added ocv as a subView of scv. Initially i set the content size of scv to the frame size of ocv. But at run time I have to increase the width of ocv because I keep adding subviews onto ocv that extend beyond the left boundary of ocv. Now when I set a new contentSize for my scrollView, It scrolls to show the right side of ocv while the content I want to see is on the left.

Same is the case with top. I keep adding subviews beyond the top boundry of ocv, but i cant scroll to see the top part, i can only scroll to see the bottom empty part..please suggest me a solution..

Comment: Basically i am building a tree in ocv where each node is a UIButton. At some point of time the leaves go beyond the left boundary of ocv. Then what i do is increase the width of ocv (ocvWidth = ocvWidth + buttonWidth ). Then again set the scv's contentSize to ocv's frame Size

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is simple. Can u please check if u have selected sc are being checked in your 
Interface builder? If everything is fine there, then please increase the height of your scroll view namely scv and also specify your UIView and the additions of subviews to it through code rather than from Interface builder?

Comment: If u are not using IB, then through CGRectmake increase the size of scroll view based on the size of the UIView plus some extra size. ie: If suppose the height of UIScrollView = UIview size plus some extra size.i believe this would be of some help